# Как создать word документ с макросом?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, ms-word

Как создать word документ с макросом? Т.е скрипт создает word документ и добавляет в него макрос, который я укажу. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: А как вы создаете word-документ? Через какую-то библиотеку?

Comment: Пока никак, нужно чтобы документ был с макросом.

Comment: А формат важен? Есть doc и docx, и они сильно отличаются -- первый бинарный формат, второй -- текстовый (zip-архив с файлами в xml)

Comment: Формат не важен

Comment: Гугление не дало четкого ответа: [тут python-docx](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/284) обсуждали как макросы засунуть, а [тут docxtpl -- шаблонизатор docx](https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) и можно сделать такой трюк: создать документ с макросом, заполнить его специальными вставками и заполнить их через docxtpl

Comment: Ключевой момент в ответе: какие можно использовать средства? Дело в том, что есть решение: создать док, добавить макрос и сохранить док как docm. Реализуется при помощи VB-скриптов и, конечно же, MSWord-ом. Допусловием является разрешение запуска макросов и разрешение доступа к объектной модели Word. VBS встроен во все версии Windows. Я так понял, вопросом предполагается, что MS Word уже установлен. Поэтому рекомендую [воспользоваться](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454673/vbscript-to-add-macro-to-ms-word) имеющимися средствами. P.S. существует решение и для импорта bas-модулей.